# How to write shell script for mongo?

Tags: mongodb, shell, aggregation-framework

Help me,
I need to write shell script for mongo

code::
`mongo data --eval "db.collection1.aggregate({$lookup:{from: "collection2", localField: "id",  foreignField: "id",  as: "arrCol" }})"`

but return error
SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell eval):1:36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script fragment should not contain double quotes. You should use single quotes for strings in your query:

> mongo data --eval "db.collection1.aggregate({$lookup:{from:
>   'collection2', localField: 'id',  foreignField: 'id',  as: 'arrCol'
>   }})"

Otherwise `"db.collection1.aggregate({$lookup:{from: "` will be interprented as JavaScript fragment which you are passing.